# characterisation of a dense subset in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Using only the definition that $M \subseteq X$ is dense in X if $\overline{M} = X$, I want to show for any subset $M \subseteq X$ that:

M is dense in X $\Longleftrightarrow U \cap M \neq \emptyset$ for all non-empty open subsets $U \subset X$.

Thanks in advance. Intuitively, it seems to be quite logical, especially when considering the example of $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$. But how can it be proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $M$ is dense and let $\varnothing \neq O \subset X$ be open.

Since $O \neq \varnothing$, there exists $x_0 \in O$. $O$ is open, so there's $\delta > 0$ such that $B(x_0, \delta) \subset O$.

Since $M$ is dense, $x_0 \in cl(M)$. Then, $B(x_0, \delta) \cap M \neq \varnothing$. Then..

For the other direction, suppose: $\forall$ open $\varnothing \neq O \subset  X$, $O \cap M \neq \varnothing$.

Let $x \in M$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. What about the open set $B(x, \epsilon)$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For any set $M$, $(\overline M)^c$ is the interior of $M^c$.

Answer (score 0):

The closure of a set $M$ can be defined as the smallest closed set containing $M$ or equivalently as $M$ along with all limit points of $M$. In one direction, use the first definition and that if $M$ is disjoint from a nonempty open set $U$, then $M\subseteq U^c\subset X$. For the other way, use the second definition and that if $M$ intersects every open set, then every point of $X$ is in $M$ or is a limit point of $M$.